# nested list css rules to support unlimited depth

Tags: css

i have the following css:

```
.navi-live ol{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navi-live li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navi-live ol .nav-item-contents{
  padding-left:20px;
}
.navi-live ol ol .nav-item-contents{
  padding-left:40px;
}
.navi-live ol ol ol .nav-item-contents{
  padding-left:60px;
}
.navi-live ol ol ol ol .nav-item-contents{
  padding-left:80px;
}
.navi-live ol ol ol ol ol .nav-item-contents{
  padding-left:100px;
}
```

This works (I dont want to indent the li or ol but indent the content as if the li and ol are indented), but limits me to the number of css rules I have created.

How do i do the above without the limitation of having to create a new rule for every new indentation level i want to support?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4hjp/1/

Thanks,

Comment: To be honest, if your going more than several indents deep you are probably doing something wrong. Revise strategy, think UX.

Comment: umm sorry but. you have 20 padding on everything. why dont you add padding-left:20px; to .nav-item-contents

Comment: need to see some html structure for this as if you are nesting the `.nav-item-contents` you should just apply it once and it will increment.  If you aren't nesting them then you will need to apply the css rules for each level

Comment: ErikMes: If I just add 20px to .nav-item-contents then what will make it indent the more ol's are inside each other?

Comment: HTML please. What element has the `nav-item-contents` class?

Comment: If you please provide a jsFiddle that'd be great :)

Comment: updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4hjp/1/

Comment: @Alex: if you take a look at the jsfiddle you will see I am trying to build a navigation builder, I think what I am trying to do is not incorrect UX.

Comment: @Jaay done: jsfiddle.net/k4hjp/1

Comment: @erikMes If you look you will see I have removing indentation from the ol's so adding padding-left:20px to all .nav-item-contents will not indent depending on the nesting of the ol's. I will just get a flat column of .nav-item-contents down the page

Comment: I see this as a valid problem.  I'm trying to do something similar but with nested colors as apposed to padding.  I want to support recursive lists that alternate colors or use a list of colors and then "restart" in the list when the depth is longer than the list of colors.  I'm surprised there isn't a solution similar to how we have `nth-child()` but instead, something like `nth-depth()`.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to do a simple select of all the `nav-item-content` divs, iterate through each one while incrementing the padding variable.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LN4vf/)

```
//put this inside a function and call it when you want to append to the navigation
var padding = 20;
$('.nav-item-contents').each(function(){
    $(this).css('padding-left',padding+'px');
    padding+=20;
});
```

### EDIT

Added a demonstration of how to append children: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LN4vf/1/).

Comment: Is this not possible with css? You look to be manually indenting each .nav-item-contents when i only want to indent as far is it is nested in ol's? It would need to be something like: number_of_nested_depth * 20

Comment: @lukemh No, number_of_nested_depth * 20 is incorrect: you would be incrementing exponentially and not linearly. The `padding+=20` increments an additional 20px for every child it finds. This is the linear equation you want to use. You will see a button that says to append children in the jsfiddle in my edit. Click this infinite times and you will see my demonstration is working.

Comment: no. I am looking for a css solution. This also indents incorrectly.

Comment: @lukemh Did you find any css solution till now ?